# SVG ошибка отображения в Firefox и IE

Tags: xml, svg, internet-explorer, firefox

Не отображаеться SVG задаваемый как фоновое изображение в Firefox и IE.

```css
.bl_catalog__main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.decor-likeLabel:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  width: 60px;
  min-height: 40px;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg version="1.1" id="likeLine" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 60 40" fill="#fff"><polyline points="0,0 35,0 58,40 0,40 0,0"></polyline></svg>') 0 0 no-repeat;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="bl_catalog__main decor-likeLabel">TEST</h1>
```

При инспектировании в Firefox выдает [image: Ошибка SVG], не знаю как исправить.

Comment: а так `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg...`?

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, а в чем разница?  Вроде у него так и есть...

Comment: `utf8` нет. посмотрел ошибку и методом тыка поудалял атрибуты. В ff заработало после удаления fill в svg (его можно в саму фигуру перекинуть)

Comment: background: url('data:image/svg+xml, <svg version="1.1" id="likeLine" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 60 40"><polyline fill="#fff" points="0,0 35,0 58,40 0,40 0,0"></polyline></svg>') 0 0 no-repeat; Ничего не изменилось, всё равно не отображает в FF

Answer (score -2):

Вставляйте svg как img

Т.е.

```
background: url(путь/fon.svg);
```